# MySQL loop through variable

Tags: mysql

I have a variable @ids = "894,891,896,899..."

What I like to do is the following

```
loop @id: @ids
     INSERT INTO `testcases_types` (`testcase_id`, `type_id`) VALUES (@id, '57');
     INSERT INTO `testcases_types` (`testcase_id`, `type_id`) VALUES (@id, '58');
     INSERT INTO `testcases_types` (`testcase_id`, `type_id`) VALUES (@id, '59');
     INSERT INTO `testcases_types` (`testcase_id`, `type_id`) VALUES (@id, '60');
end loop
```

So I tried a lot now , but I cannot find out the right syntax. I do not want to write a procedure. I just want to execute it once .

Comment: Is `@id` a string? where you get the `type_id` from? or is autonumeric. Show us `create table` for `testcases_types`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: @ids is a string . Yes. As you can see by the quotes.

Comment: ' I do not want to write a procedure' - you cannot use loops outwith stored programs (procedures,function,triggers,events)

Comment: What about the `type_id` ??